# Expected '}' and instead saw '=' in expression

Tags: sapui5

I'm currently learning SAP/Open UI5. I have followed some of the tutorials on the [openSAP](https://open.sap.com) platform. Now I am trying by myself to modify a project (created from the template SAP Fiori Worklist Application). I'm editing the whole project in the Web IDE.

**The problem**

To come up with the problem I have is, that I have a table with four columns in my XML view. All these columns are filled with data from the OData service.

```
<ColumnListItem
    type="Navigation"
    press=".onPress">
    <cells>
        <ObjectIdentifier
            title="{Name}"
            text="{ProductID}"/>
        <Text text="{SupplierName}"></Text>
        <Text text="{= ${WeightMeasure} == 0 ? '-' : ${WeightMeasure}}"></Text>
        <ObjectNumber
            number="{
                path: 'Price',
                formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit'
            }"
            unit="{CurrencyCode}"/>
    </cells>
</ColumnListItem>
```

The code snippet above is in the `items` aggregation. When I now start the standalone application, normally the records from the backend appearing. Since I have implemented now the third row with the WeightMeasure expression (`{= ${WeightMeasure} == 0 ? '-' : ${WeightMeasure}}`), I receive the following error in the Dev console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Expected '}' and instead saw '=' in expression binding {= ${WeightMeasure} == 0 ? 'Hello' : ${WeightMeasure}} at position 20
    at w (BindingParser-dbg.js:445)
    at Function.a.complexParser [as bindingParser] (BindingParser-dbg.js:482)
    at p (XMLTemplateProcessor-dbg.js:47)
    at K (XMLTemplateProcessor-dbg.js:732)
    at J (XMLTemplateProcessor-dbg.js:630)
    at I (XMLTemplateProcessor-dbg.js:566)
    at l1 (XMLTemplateProcessor-dbg.js:862)
```

The value it self does exist and also show up when I just enter the variable.

**What I have tried**

Of course, I have checked first the docs and general the internet. I have found the [article for expression binding](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_uiaddon10/1.17/en-US/da/f6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0/content.htm) again. But when I have compared the example to my version, it really looks identical. Unless my version does not work.

Also, I have tried it with several relative paths, but with no result in the end. It really looks like there is a syntax error somewhere or what could be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently had this problem too. Try replacing `==` with `===`:

```
text="{= ${WeightMeasure} === 0 ? '-' : ${WeightMeasure}}"
```

Or simplified

```
text="{= ${WeightMeasure} || '-'}"
```

The issue is that UI5 supports only *strict equality operators* (`===` or `!==`) in *[Expression Binding](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0)*.